# Failed to compile 'dispatch' is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I was coding a counter but I have an error like that:

> Line 11:29:  'dispatch' is not defined  no-undef

and here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import {useSelector,useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {increment} from './actions'

function App() {
  const counter = useSelector(state => state.counter);
  const isLogged = useSelector(state => state.isLogged);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Counter {counter}</h1>
      <button onClick={()=> dispatch(increment())}>+</button> //line:11
      <button>-</button>
      {isLogged ? <h3>Value info can't be display</h3>: '' }
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

as understood increment is an action. Can you help me please :)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You imported `useDispatch` from `react-redux` but not used it.

```
import React from "react";
import {useSelector,useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {increment} from './actions'

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch(); // Use it
  const counter = useSelector(state => state.counter);
  const isLogged = useSelector(state => state.isLogged);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Counter {counter}</h1>
      <button onClick={()=> dispatch(increment())}>+</button> //line:11
      <button>-</button>
      {isLogged ? <h3>Value info can't be display</h3>: '' }
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

`dispatch` is indeed not defined. You probably have to do something like:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my error Thanks to:

> Thiago Loddi, Tigran Abrahamyan